# angular ajax call timing out on OPTIONS request, possible CORS issue

Tags: ajax, angularjs, nginx, cors

I have a web application (www.webapp.com) that is running on a **different** server trying to make api calls with my back end rest server (api.example.com). I'm trying to interact with the web application through a web browser but the ajax calls are not working.  For example, trying to make a request to api.example.com/endpoint.

Any clue what I'm missing here?

On Chrome's console I get:

```
OPTIONS https://api.example.com/endpoint net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

On Firefox's console I get:

```
OPTIONS https://api.example.com/endpoint [250ms]  
null
```

I am using nginx to serve the rest server.  The location section of the nginx.conf contains:

```
location /{
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;

     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Header' 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'POST, GET, OPTIONS';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://example.com';
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://www.webapp.com';
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'POST, GET, OPTIONS';
         add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' '1728000';
         add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8';
         return 200;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this document can help you

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1972[enter link description here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1972)

i had previously this problem for cross domain api calls .. angular sending one option call before post call and it waits for a success option request .what i done was i created a option handler also it return success ..i am not sure that is the current way but it helps me to solve that issue

```
@POST
@Path("createNote")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponceMsg createNotePost(@FormParam("subject") String subject,
           @FormParam("description") String description,
           @FormParam("requestId") int requestId){

    requestProcess.createNewNote(requestId,subject,description);
    return new ResponceMsg();
}

@OPTIONS
@Path("createNote")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Void createNote(){
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You back end server my be setup such that it know that the client is to be trusted. Processing the Options is for the server container to do, Tomcat / Apache and there is not work around other then specifically coding the URL of the client into the server config.

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with nginx but here is a document that discusses setting up CORS.
See here: http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html